# Concat bytes array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, string-concatenation, usbserial

I am receiving data from serial port RS232 like `[00000]` continuously per 100 ms, but if i use usb to serial converter data is splitting into multiple parts if i append that in a text box i am getting output like `[00000][00000][00000][00000][00000]`, here comes the problem i want to pick the each array separately like `[00000]`  what i am getting is

```
[
0 
000
0
]
```

so i tried to concat it in a variable upto the string getting into the length of 7, if it 7 i will write it into another variable and clear pervious array still i could't achieve the result.

```
Dim k As String
k = k & [text]
If k.Length = 7 Then
   Me.RichTextBox1.Text = k
   k = ""
End If
```

how to get the desired result.

Comment: Check each `[text]` before appending to `k` to see if there are any unprintable characters like char(0), 13, etc, which will result in length being more than expected. Let's say at the end of each `[text]`, there is chr(0) appended at the end, so the `k.length` will be 2, then 4 (2+2), then 8 (4+4), and so on. So your if statement will never hit true since it checks for 7. If there are any unprintable characters, trim them first before apending to your variable.

Comment: @ajakblackgoat exactly the same i am facing, thanks i will try

Comment: I suggest you printout the [text].length to debug output to see what their actual length is for each data received.

Comment: i did that already, result is like 2, 1 5, 4, 1, 1, 2

Comment: Exactly, for the example data input in your question, it should be 1, 1 3, 1, 1